# Why after the while loop I am only getting last row value?

Tags: loops, perl

This is the files I am reading,

```
#Log1
Time    Src_id  Des_id  Address
0   34  56  x9870
2   36  58  x9872
4   38  60  x9874
6   40  62  x9876
8   42  64  x9878
```

```
#Log2
Time    Src_id  Des_id  Address
1   35  57  x9871
3   37  59  x9873
5   39  61  x9875
7   41  63  x9877
9   43  65  x9879
```

This the code I wrote where I am reading line by line and then spliting it

```
#!usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my $log1_file = "log1.log";
my $log2_file = "log2.log";

open(IN1, "<$log1_file" ) or die "Could not open file $log1_file: $!";
open(IN2, "<$log2_file" ) or die "Could not open file $log2_file: $!";

my $i_d1;
my $i_d2;
my @fields1;
my @fields2;
while (my $line = <IN1>) {
    @fields1 = split " ", $line;
   }
while (my $line = <IN2>) {
    @fields2 = split " ", $line;
   }
 
   print "@fields1\n";
   print "@fields2\n";
   

close IN1; 
close IN2;
```

Output I am getting

```
8 42 64 x9878
9 43 65 x9879
```

Output Desired

```
Time    Src_id  Des_id  Address
0   34  56  x9870
2   36  58  x9872
4   38  60  x9874
6   40  62  x9876
8   42  64  x9878
9 43 65 x9879
Time    Src_id  Des_id  Address
1   35  57  x9871
3   37  59  x9873
5   39  61  x9875
7   41  63  x9877
9   43  65  x9879
```

If I use  `push(@fields1 , split " ", $line);` I am getting output like this,

```
Time Src_id Des_id Address 0 34 56 x9870 B 36 58 x9872 D 38 60 x9874 F 40 62 x9876 H 42 64 x9878
```

It should print whole array but printing just last row?
Also after this I need to compare both the "Times" part of both log & print in sequence way but don't know how to run both array simultaneously in while loop?
Please suggest in standard way without any modules because I need to run this in someone else server.

Comment: `cat log1.log log2.log | sort -n` perhaps

Comment: It's a oneliner. `$ perl -e"print sort { $a <=> $b} grep /^\d/,<>" log1.log log2.log`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following code demonstrates how to read and print log files
(OP does not specify why he splits lines into fields)

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my $fname1  = 'log1.txt';
my $fname2  = 'log2.txt';
my $div     = "\t";

my $file1   = read_file($fname1);
my $file2   = read_file($fname2);

print_file($file1,$div);
print_file($file2,$div);

sub read_file {
    my $fname = shift;
    
    my @data;
    
    open my $fh, '<', $fname
        or die "Couldn't read $fname";
        
    while( <$fh> ) {
        chomp;
        next if /^#Log/;
        push @data, [split];
    }
        
    close $fh;
    
    return \@data;
}

sub print_file {
    my $data = shift;
    my $div  = shift;
    
    say join($div,@{$_}) for @{$data};
}
```

Output

```
Time    Src_id  Des_id  Address
0       34      56      x9870
2       36      58      x9872
4       38      60      x9874
6       40      62      x9876
8       42      64      x9878
Time    Src_id  Des_id  Address
1       35      57      x9871
3       37      59      x9873
5       39      61      x9875
7       41      63      x9877
9       43      65      x9879
```

Let's assume that OP wants to merge two files into one with sorted lines on `Time` field

- read files into `%data` hash with `Time` field as key
- print header (`@fields`)
- print hash values sorted on `Time` key

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my(@fields,%data);

my $fname1  = 'log1.txt';
my $fname2  = 'log2.txt';

read_data($fname1);
read_data($fname2);

say join("\t",@fields);
say join("\t",@{$data{$_}}) for sort { $a <=> $b } keys %data;

sub read_data {
    my $fname = shift;
    
    open my $fh, '<', $fname
        or die "Couldn't open $fname";
        
    while( <$fh> ) {
        next if /^#Log/;
        if( /^Time/ ) {
            @fields = split;
        } else {
            my @line = split;
            $data{$line[0]} = \@line;
        }
    }
        
    close $fh;
}
```

Output

```
Time    Src_id  Des_id  Address
0       34      56      x9870
1       35      57      x9871
2       36      58      x9872
3       37      59      x9873
4       38      60      x9874
5       39      61      x9875
6       40      62      x9876
7       41      63      x9877
8       42      64      x9878
9       43      65      x9879
```

Comment: This second code assumes that the values in `Time` are unique (because hash keys are unique), and that they never go higher than 9 (because alphabetical sort will put 10 before 9, for example). If any of that is not true, this code is broken. Also, assigning to global variables in subroutines is bad practice.

Comment: @TLP - you should try to use `format` and `write` in subroutine with local variables -- it would be a good exercise without global variables. Even in packages some variables are global -- C/C++ has `static` variable classifier for such purpose. Perhaps you luck understanding what global variables are used for and what advantage they provide.

Comment: You could just return the values. You were too interested in reusing the sub, which is the wrong design choice. And you are still overwriting hash values that are not unique. And there is no reason to get toxic and personal: Fix the problems instead

Comment: @PolarBear @TLP, Can you explain these lines `$data{$line[0]} = \@line;` & `@{$data{$_}}) for sort { $a <=> $b } keys %data;`. And also if the time is same for two cases it's only showing one. Thankyou.

Comment: @HG That's what I meant when I said that it will not work unless the Times are unique. It might work if you rewrite the code to store an array of values in the Time hash key. But then again, I believe my one-liner in the comments is sufficient to handle this problem, unless we are talking about something more complicated than sorting log files.

Comment: @HG -- in your original post you must state that `Time` can have duplicates (otherwise it assumed that no duplicates allowed). `$data{$line[0]} = \@line` -- `%data` is a hash, `@line` is array -- meaning put reference to array `@line` into hash `%data` for a key stored in first element `0`of array `line`.  `sort { $a <=> $b} keys %data` -- take and sort keys of hash `%data` numerically. `@{$data{$_}}` -- take element of hash `%data` stored under key stored in special variable `$_` [value obtained in `for` loop] and use it as array [value stored in the hash `%data` is a reference to an array].

Comment: @PolarBear Thankyou for explaining.

Answer (score 2):

Because `@fields*` gets overwritten during each loop. You need this:

```
while(my $line = <IN1>){
    my @tmp = split(" ", $line);
    push(@fields1, \@tmp);
}
foreach $item (@fields1){
    print("@{$item}\n");
}
```

Then `@fields1` contains references pointing to the `split`ed array.

The final `@fields1` looks like:

```
@fields1 = (
  <ref> ----> ["0", "34", "56", "x9870"]
  <ref> ----> ["2", "36", "58", "x9872"]
  ...
)
```

The `print` will print:

```
Time Src_id Des_id Address
0 34 56 x9870
2 36 58 x9872
4 38 60 x9874
6 40 62 x9876
8 42 64 x9878
```

And I guess it would be better if you do `chomp($line)`.

But I'd like to simply do `push(@fields1, $line)`. And `split` each array item when in comparison stage.

To compare the content of 2 files, I personally would use 2 `while` loops to read into 2 arrays just like what you have done. Then do the comparison in one `for` or `foreach`.

Comment: If I use ```push``` the whole data coming in single line and not as given in input file. And for the comparing the contents I use two while loop. 2nd while loop inside the 1st one but that isn't working for me. Can you elaborate the while loop part ?

Comment: @HG Elaborate which `while`?

Comment: You do not need `chomp` when you split on whitespace.

Comment: @TLP OK. It's just my habit.

Comment: @Light, Hey still getting everything on same line.

Comment: @HG I added full code to generate `@fields1` and how to print it.

Answer (score 1):

You can merge the log files using paste, and read the resulting merged file one line at a time. This is more elegant and saves RAM. Here is an example of a possible comparison of `time1` and `time2`, writing STDOUT and STDERR into separate files. The example prints into STDOUT all the input fields if `time1 < time2 and time1 < 4`, otherwise prints a warning into STDERR:

```
cat > log1.log <<EOF
Time    Src_id  Des_id  Address
0   34  56  x9870
2   36  58  x9872
4   38  60  x9874
6   40  62  x9876
8   42  64  x9878
EOF


cat > log2.log <<EOF
Time    Src_id  Des_id  Address
1   35  57  x9871
3   37  59  x9873
5   39  61  x9875
7   41  63  x9877
9   43  65  x9879
EOF


# Paste files side by side, skip header, read data lines together, compare and print:

paste log1.log log2.log | \
    tail -n +2 | \
    perl -lane '
BEGIN {
    for $file_num (1, 2)  { push @col_names, map { "$_$file_num" } qw( time src_id des_id address ) }
}
my %val;
@val{ @col_names } = @F;
if ( $val{time1} < $val{time2} and $val{time1} < 4) {
    print join "\t", @val{ @col_names};
} else {
    warn "not found: @val{ qw( time1 time2 ) }";
}
' 1>out.tsv 2>out.log
```

Output:

```
% cat out.tsv
0       34      56      x9870   1       35      57      x9871
2       36      58      x9872   3       37      59      x9873
% cat out.log
not found: 4 5 at -e line 10, <> line 3.
not found: 6 7 at -e line 10, <> line 4.
not found: 8 9 at -e line 10, <> line 5.
```

The Perl one-liner uses these command line flags:
`-e` : Tells Perl to look for code in-line, instead of in a file.
`-n` : Loop over the input one line at a time, assigning it to `$_` by default.
`-l` : Strip the input line separator (`"\n"` on *NIX by default) before executing the code in-line, and append it when printing.
`-a` : Split `$_` into array `@F` on whitespace or on the regex specified in `-F` option.

**SEE ALSO:**
[`perldoc perlrun`: how to execute the Perl interpreter: command line switches](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches)

Comment: Is there really any point in changing delimiter in the log files? Or showing how you create the log files in your answer?

Comment: @TLP Thank you for suggesting to keep the log file delimiters as is. I updated the answer. Indeed, there is usually no point to change log files in place, and here is no exception. Regarding your second point: I had to create log files somehow, as an example input, to show [mre] - I wish the OP included something like this (the actual commands). The commands I showed make it easier for anyone else who wants to answer the question. They can just copy and paste it into the shell in one fell swoop. No need for the editor, etc.