# How to arrange/sort the first column of array in increasing order in Perl?

Tags: arrays, regex, perl, hash

Here my file look like,

```
Time   Send     Receive  Address
100    35       57       x9871
03     37       59       x9873
45     39       61       x9875
90     41       63       x9877
1234   43       65       x9879
45     76       89       x9768
```

I want to arrange the array according to time in increasing order and it should look like,

```
Time   Send     Receive  Address
03     37       59       x9873
45     76       89       x9768
45     39       61       x9875
90     41       63       x9877
100    35       57       x9871
1234   43       65       x9879
```

If time is same it should print both the time. Till now I only able to read the file line by line.

```
#!usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

my $logout_file = "ll.log";
my $temp1 = "temp1.log";

open(OUT, "+>>$logout_file") or die "Could not open file $logout_file: $!";   
open (tmp,"<tempp1") or die "Couldn't open $fname";
while(my $aa= <tmp> ) {
@fields = split " ",$aa;
say OUT join("|",@fields));
}
    close fh;
}
```

Main thing is I don't know how should I start. I searched many things on google but didn't find anything relevant. Please any one suggest how to do it in standard way (while loop or foreach loop) without using any modules. Thankyou.

Update:
If some columns in particular row increases like, (log2.txt)

```
Time   Send     Receive  Address
100    35       57       x9871
03     37       59       x9873
45     39       61       x9875    x7890   x8976
90     41       63       x9877    x8765
1234   43       65       x9879
45     76       89       x9768
```

Update using `Data::Dumper` output looks like,

```
$VAR1 = {
          '9' => [
                   '9  41 63 x9877'
                 ],
          '345678' => [
                        '345678 4554 5445 5656'
                      ],
          '3' => [
                   '3  37 59 x9873'
                 ],
         
        };
```

Output

```
Time   Send     Receive  Address
03     37       59       x9873
03     37       59       x9873
45     39       61       x9875
45     76       89       x9768
45     39       61       x9875    x7890   x8976
45     76       89       x9768
90     41       63       x9877
90     41       63       x9877    x8765
100    35       57       x9871
100    35       57       x9871
1234   43       65       x9879
1234   43       65       x9879
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate what does mean by `Time` here? Is it a seconds? For eg. 100s, 3s, 45s..?

Comment: @vkk05, Yes we can take it in seconds also.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/64121838/725418

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Algorithm for this problem is following

- use `Time` field as a key for hash
- push read line into an array which is a part of hash with `Time` key
- print header
- print hash on sorted keys for each array element

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my $fname1 = 'log1.txt';
my $fname2 = 'log2.txt';

my($header,%data);

read_file($fname1);
read_file($fname2);

say $header;
for my $time ( sort { $a <=> $b } keys %data ) {
    say for @{$data{$time}};
}

exit 0;

sub read_file {
    my $fname = shift;
    
    open my $fh, '<', $fname
        or die "Couldn't open $fname";
    
    while( <$fh> ) {
        chomp;
        next if /^#Log/;
        my @line = split;
        if( /^Time/ ) {
            $header = $_;
        } else {
            push @{$data{$line[0]}},$_;
        }
    }
    
    close $fh;
}
```

Output

```
Time   Send     Receive  Address
03     37       59       x9873
03     37       59       x9873
45     39       61       x9875
45     76       89       x9768
45     76       89       x9768
45     39       61       x9875
90     41       63       x9877
90     41       63       x9877
100    35       57       x9871
100    35       57       x9871
```

Comment: Your answer works now, glad to see you used my suggestions. Though I would still not have used a sub, and not used globals inside it. Using the diamond operator and not hard coding the file names would make it more reusable. Technically using a hash was not needed either, could have used a two-dimensional array and stored the Time in index 0 and string in index 1, without a need for an array in the identical Times. It is a sort of [Schwartzian transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform), `for (map { $_->[1] } sort { $a->[0] <=> $b->[0] } @data ) { say }`. Good job.

Comment: @TLP -- I don't care about your suggestions, I used healthy sense -- this time OP stated that input data have duplicates for `Time` field.

Comment: No point in being toxic. This is a learning environment.

Comment: @PolarBear, In my code if I write `for` in `say for @{$data{$time}};` it's not printing anything and if I remove `for` then keys which are same are printing on the same line.

Comment: @HG -- you should look at your data with **use [Data::Dumper](https://perldoc.perl.org/Data::Dumper)**, it will help you to figure out how your data organized.

Comment: @PolarBear, Using Data::Dumper I am getting output like this(see update part in ques) not like what I want. Can you suggest anyway to do it?

Comment: @HG -- I have edited your question and assigned name `log2.txt` to piece of data before you `Data::Dumper` output. Then I run perl script and added it's output to your question. I assume that you have perl code which is different from my sample.

Comment: @PolarBear, See I am using perl 5.20.1. Is this can also affect?

Answer (score 2):

As I mentioned in [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64121838/725418) on this topic, this can be solved with a one-liner.

```
perl -e'print sort { $a <=> $b} grep /^\d/,<>' log1.log log2.log
```

You can just put that code into a file and run it like so:

```
$ perl foo.pl log1.log log2.log > log_all.log
```

You would need to fix the headers yourself.

Explanation:

`<>` in list context reads all the lines of input (can be both stdin and file data), `grep /^\d/` removes all lines that do not begin with numbers, `sort { $a <=> $b}` sorts the remaining lines numerically and `print` prints them.

You do not need to split the lines or do any processing.

This code has a caveat, in that it will cast the entire line of the file into a number. I.e. it will take a string such as `03     37       59       x9873` and cast it into a number `03`. When it does that, it will use the first string `03` and ignore the rest. If you have warnings enabled, you will get a lot of warnings, so we turn those off because we know what we are doing: We are just sorting lines by the first number on the line. And since we do not have any lines which do not begin with numbers, we can do it like this.

If I try my oneliner on your new input I get:

```
03     37       59       x9873
03     37       59       x9873
45     39       61       x9875
45     76       89       x9768
45     76       89       x9768
45     39       61       x9875
90     41       63       x9877
90     41       63       x9877
100    35       57       x9871
100    35       57       x9871
1234   43       65       x9879
1234   43       65       x9879
```

Which seems to fit your requirement.

And if you really want to use `use warnings` you can turn off these warnings lexically with `no warnings 'numeric'`.

Comment: OP's output includes header, your output omits header.

Comment: @PolarBear Yes, I mention that in my answer

Answer (score 1):

See if this could help you.

I am considering each line number as a key for the hash, based on the line number the entire line data will get stored in the hash.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use feature 'say';

my (@fields, %hash);
my $count = 0;

while (my $aa = <DATA>){
    
    next if ($aa =~ /Time\s+Send\s+Receive\s+Address/); 
    
    $count++;
    
    @fields = split " ",$aa;
    
    $hash{$count}{TIME}    = $fields[0];
    $hash{$count}{SEND}    = $fields[1];
    $hash{$count}{RECEIVE} = $fields[2];
    $hash{$count}{ADDRESS} = $fields[3];
}

my @headers = ("Time", "Send", "Receive", "Address");
say join("\t", @headers);

foreach my $key (sort { $hash{$a}->{TIME} <=> $hash{$b}->{TIME} } keys %hash){
    say "$hash{$key}{TIME}\t$hash{$key}{SEND}\t$hash{$key}{RECEIVE}\t$hash{$key}{ADDRESS}";
}

__DATA__
Time   Send     Receive  Address
100    35       57       x9871
03     37       59       x9873
45     39       61       x9875
90     41       63       x9877
1234   43       65       x9879
45     76       89       x9768
```

**Output:**

```
Time    Send    Receive Address
03      37      59      x9873
45      76      89      x9768
45      39      61      x9875
90      41      63      x9877
100     35      57      x9871
1234    43      65      x9879
```

Comment: Instead of using a hash with increasing numbers as keys, and then sort those keys, why not just use an array?

Comment: @vkk05, Can you check the updated part in question? Thankyou. For that case I add ` $hash{$count}{ADD} = $fields[5..$length];` length is the row length but this isn't working. You have any suggestion.